# I want to buy game items on my deceased husbands Galaxy Tab 2 , I dont know his password. Is it possible?

Tags: password, samsung-galaxy-tab-2-10.1, in-app-purchase

When my husband became ill I promised him I would keep his game going until he could, unfortunately he died. I am still playing his game on his Galaxy Tab 2 and wanted to buy him some game items. When I tried I was asked for his google password which I don't know. Is there anyway I can buy him game items using my PayPal account?

Comment: Go into phone settings>accounts>Google>add account. Add your email address, now when you try buying an item it might give you the option to buy it using the added account

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I have done that but unfortunately the game (Clash of Clans) is in my husbands name and when I try to buy him in app purchases it comes up with his email, which I cannot change and asks for his password. I can't get any further. Even if I could remember the password as he's been gone 2 years the account will now no longer function. Any more advice would be very welcomed

Comment: that's what i was afraid of. My other advice would be to go to Gmail.com and try the forgot password option he might have had your email address as backup or something

Comment: Thanks again for putting so much thought into this for me. I did that and tried a number of passwords I thought he might have used but I got nowhere. I even tried putting in MY phone number but nothing happened. It would seem Google's security is fairly tight (unless you're a hacker which I'm not obviously lol) All I want to do is fulfill a promise. I'm at a loss to know what to do next but am very grateful for your help

Comment: SharonRiley,

That's so nice of you to keep his game going for him. That really touched me.

Don't give up yet! I hope my answer still gets to you if you come back to this site.
Hopefully google will let you get the account back!

Answer (score 2):

## You CAN get full access to his gmail and recover his password!!!

Google has a way of recover the password for deceased people.

https://support.google.com/accounts/troubleshooter/6357590?hl=en

Click and fill out the forum that says,

#### "Obtain data from a deceased user's account"

## Don't log out of his account and log in with yours!!!!!!

People have suggested in comments above to do so. **DON'T** Some (not all) apps will detect fraud if you remove the account the game was purchased from!!!

Comment: Oh Thank you so much! I have found Google's phone number and intend to phone them on Monday explaining my dilemma but until now thought I had no hope. I knew I couldn't put Mick's game in my name and frankly didn't want to - I'm only playing it for him. I will let you know the outcome, Thank you so much I really thought I was dead in the water. To my knowledge I have never broken a promise and didn't want red tape to be the cause of the first and most important

Comment: You are filling out the forum that says "Obtain data from a deceased user's account" right?

@SharonRiley

Comment: Yes Lateral, I'm hoping I will get the information I need that way